# .NET Regular Expression to match any kind of letter from any language

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, unicode, asp.net-mvc-2

Which regular expression can I use to match (allow) any kind of letter from any language?

I need to match any letter including any diacritics (e.g., á, ü, ñ)
and exclude any kind of symbol (math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc.) and punctuation characters.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 with .NET 4. I’ve tried this annotation in my view model

```
[RegularExpression(@"\p{L}*", ...
```

and this one

```
[RegularExpression(@"\p{L}\p{M}*", ...
```

but client-side validation rejects accented characters.

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for all your answers. Your suggestions work but only for .NET, and the problem here is that it also uses the regex for client-side validation with JavaScript.

I had to go with

```
[^0-9_\|°¬!#\$%/\\\(\)\?¡¿\+\{\}\[\]:\.\,;@ª^\*<>=&]
```

which is very ugly and does not cover all scenarios but is the closest thing to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to watch out for is the client-side regex. It uses javascript regex on the client side and .net regex on the server side. Javascript won't support this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx):

> Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a Unicode letter.

With .Net 4.0:

```
string onlyLetters = String.Concat(str.Where(Char.IsLetter));
```

On 3.5 `String.Concat` only excepts an array, so you should also call `ToArray`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, not necessarely the question is to solve a problem, maybe it was made to learn REGEX, i don't know. Ok, it may be a problem, but he specifically asks how to do that with regex (through the question, a tag, and even the title), which is clearly accomplishable. +1 for solving the 'problem', -1 for not answering the question. Neutral.

Comment: @Marcelo - Looking more closely on the question, you are probably right. `[` suggest this is used as an Attribute, and possibly cannot be replaced by code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is more likely to the fact that you will only have to have **one** alpha-char, because the regex will match anything that has at least one char.

By adding `^` as prefix and `$` as postfix, the whole sentence should comply to your regex. So this prob works:

```
^\p{L}*$
```

Regexbuddy explains:

1. `^` Assert position at beginning of the string
2. `\p{L}` A character with the Unicode property 'letter' (any kind of letter from any kind of language)
   2a. Between zero and unlimited times, as many as possible (greedy)
3. `$` Assert position at the end of the string

Comment: `\p{L}` is the winner = "Matches any kind of letter from any language"

Answer (score 2):

`\p{L}*` should match "any kind of letter from any language". It should work, I used it in a i18n-proof [uppercase/lowercase recognition regex](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-proof-c-regex-recognizing.html) in .NET.

Comment: Then the problem might be more specific than I thought, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just had to validate a URL and I chose this regular expression in .NET.

```
^[(\p{L})?(\p{M})?-]*$
```

Begin and end with a character of any language (optionally either letters or marks) and allow hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

\w - matches any alphanumeric character (including  numbers)

In my tests it has matched:

- ã
- à
- ç
- 8
- z

and hasn't matched:

- ;
- ,
- \
- :

In case you know exactly what you want to exclude (like a little list) you cand do the following:

[^;,\`.]

which matches one time any character that isnt:

- ;
- ,
- \
- `
- .

Hope it helps!

Comment: @eagle hmm.. you're right, at least i've given an alternative. Gonna check it out though

Comment: \w - stands for Word. Not letter.

Comment: It also matches numbers which the OP does not want.

Comment: @Lukas: This is misleading. `\w` matches a single character, not a word. It will match letters, numbers and the underscore. Whether it matches only ASCII letters or Unicode letters varies between regex flavors - in .NET it's Unicode.

Comment: @Tim_Pietzcker I'm actually just learning REGEX, thank you, this was useful even for me =)

Comment: @Tim: [:word:] = \w = [A-Za-z0-9_] => Alphanumeric *characters* plus "_". (details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @Lukas, yes of course, I'm aware of this. But in your inital comment it is easy to misunderstand you when you distinguish between "word" and "letter" - I guess 90 % would think in this context that you're referring to the real-life meaning of word, i. e. a sequence of letters with semantic meaning.