# How to find out if string contains non-alpha numeric characters in C#/.NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Allowed characters are (at least) A-Z, a-z, 0-9, ö, Ö, ä, ä, å, Å and german, latvian, estonian (if any) special chars? Is there ready-made method or do i have to make blacklist (non-allowed chars) and regular expressions IsMatch? If no ready-made how to use blacklist?

Comment: Another thread having answers to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371780/ Might provide additional insight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net Regular Expression to match any kind of letter from any language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949861/net-regular-expression-to-match-any-kind-of-letter-from-any-language)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know how special characters from all those languages are categorised, but you could check if the `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` method matches what you want to do. It works at least for the digits and letters I tested:

```
string test = "Aasdf345ÅÄÖåäöéÉóÓüÜïÏôÔ";
if (test.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit)) { ... }
```

The `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` returns true for characters that are categorised in Unicode as UppercaseLetter, LowercaseLetter, TitlecaseLetter, ModifierLetter, OtherLetter, or DecimalDigitNumber.

Comment: What's test.All? That's not a string method, is it some kind of extension method? Or a LINQ method?

Comment: @Task `All` is a linq extension of string.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: Ah!  The "Extension Methods" section of the documentation is new to me, I hadn't seen that before.  I guess I've gotten too used to finding everything I need in the earlier "Properties" or "Methods" area.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Investigate `char.IsLetterOrDigit(char)`.

For example:

```
myString.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Comment: Just curious, but why was this downvoted? As far as I can tell it's a perfectly valid way of doing what the OP asked.

Comment: Ah.. just had a closer look; never noticed the 0-9 requirement in there. I've amended my answer to use `IsLetterOrDigit` instead of just `IsLetter`.

Comment: A shorthand for this is `myString.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);`

Answer (score 4):

A blacklist for characters is likely pretty large :-)

You can use the regular expression

```
^[\d\p{L}]+$
```

to match decimal digits and letters, regardless of script.

This regular expression consists of a character class containing the shorthands `\d` – which contains every digit (230 in total in the BMP) and `\p{L}` which contains every Unicode character classified as a "letter" (46817 in the BMP). Said character class is then repeated at least once and embedded between `^` and `$` – the string start and end anchors, so it matches the complete string.

For some regex engines, since you're only interested in Latin letters, apparently, you could also use

```
^[\d\p{Letter}]+$
```

However, .NET doesn't support this. The first regex mentioned above actually catches everything that's a digit or a letter in *any* script. So it will dutifully match on Indian or Arabic numerals and Hebrew, Cyrillic and other non-Latin scripts. Depending on what you want this may not be appropriate.

If that poses a problem, then I see no better option than to explicitly list the characters you want to allow. However, I consider it dangerous to assume that text in a certain language is always restricted to that language's script. If I were to write a Czech or Polish name in a German text, then I'd likely need more than just `[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]`.

Comment: thanks! can you please explain how ^[\d\p{L}]+$ works. I checked from the web but I couldn't sum it up entirely...

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to match allowed characters catch a false return.